# Call (C#) .NET Core method from C++

Tags: c#, c++, ubuntu, .net-core, cross-platform

I have 2 components:
 - .Net Core Application running on Ubuntu OS.
 - C++ shared library (.so)

Now I want C++ component to be able to call .Net Core method, either passing interface to C++ component which will use this interface to callback method implementation or passing method as a parameter to C++ component.

High-level example what I am trying to achieve:
C# component :

```
public interface IDevice
{
   void OnDataAvailable(string data);
}

public class Device: IDevice
{
   [DllImport("sampleCPPLibrary.so")]
   private static extern int SetReceiver(IDevice receiver);  
   public void OnDataAvailable(string data)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(data);
   }
   public void Initialize()
   {
      SetReceiver(IDevice(this))
   }
}
```

C++ component:

```
extern "C" {
void SetReceiver(IReceiver * receiver)
{
    receiver->OnDataAvailable(10);
}
}
```

**Basically, what I am trying to do is just to pass some kind of "callback" to C++ component and call this "callback" when some event occurs in C++ component.**

Comment: I doubt you can do it with interface (because interface means having some object that implements it). I'm not much into .Net Core, but check if [`Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_GetDelegateForFunctionPointer_System_IntPtr_System_Type_) is available to you. You can try to use it to invoke C-style callback.

Answer (score 2):

See [See this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14540) from comments I constructed code where C# calls C and gives it callback delegate. Thus from C then it calls C#, and passes additional int type argument. [See comments here from endurox project](http://www.endurox.org/issues/23), and attached c-callback.tar.gz  for working example.

Comment: From what I can tell, this is about Mono and not .NET Core.

Comment: Why you think so?

Check the Makefile there:


`all:
 clang++ -shared -fPIC -std=c++11 ./reversepinvokefromthread.cpp -o reversepinvokefromthread.so
 dotnet run`

It is running dotnet command and not mono.

Comment: Oh, that was my bad. I'd been searching for a solution and had a bunch of tabs open, so I accidentally commented in the wrong one.